# Assembly Code to C Code (Add Instruction Issues)

Tags: c, assembly, x86

So for my class project I am given a binary and what I have to do is bypass the security authentication. Now, once you change the binary to bypass the authentication, you have to create a C program that will replicate the "same" binary. Now, I have been struggling to understand what this area of the assembly code dump that I obtained does.

```
0x08048a59 <function8+54>:  mov    0x8049e50,%eax
0x08048a5e <function8+59>:  add    $0x4,%eax
0x08048a61 <function8+62>:  mov    (%eax),%eax
0x08048a63 <function8+64>:  movl   $0x8048cd4,0x4(%esp)
```

I'm not very familiar with assembly, but I got most of it figured out. This is the original/entire assembly dump that I got using GDB.

```
0x08048a23 <function8+0>:   push   %ebp
0x08048a24 <function8+1>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048a26 <function8+3>:   sub    $0x28,%esp
0x08048a29 <function8+6>:   movl   $0xd6a1a,-0x18(%ebp)
0x08048a30 <function8+13>:  mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048a33 <function8+16>:  mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
0x08048a36 <function8+19>:  mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048a39 <function8+22>:  mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
0x08048a3c <function8+25>:  movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048a43 <function8+32>:  mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048a46 <function8+35>:  mov    %eax,%edx
0x08048a48 <function8+37>:  sar    $0x1f,%edx
0x08048a4b <function8+40>:  idivl  -0x18(%ebp)
0x08048a4e <function8+43>:  imul   -0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x08048a52 <function8+47>:  imul   -0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x08048a56 <function8+51>:  mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048a59 <function8+54>:  mov    0x8049e50,%eax
0x08048a5e <function8+59>:  add    $0x4,%eax
0x08048a61 <function8+62>:  mov    (%eax),%eax
0x08048a63 <function8+64>:  movl   $0x8048cd4,0x4(%esp)
0x08048a6b <function8+72>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048a6e <function8+75>:  call   0x8048434 <strcmp@plt>
0x08048a73 <function8+80>:  test   %eax,%eax
0x08048a75 <function8+82>:  jne    0x8048a8d <function8+106>
0x08048a77 <function8+84>:  mov    $0x8048cdc,%eax
0x08048a7c <function8+89>:  mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
0x08048a7f <function8+92>:  mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
0x08048a83 <function8+96>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048a86 <function8+99>:  call   0x8048414 <printf@plt>
0x08048a8b <function8+104>: jmp    0x8048a99 <function8+118>
0x08048a8d <function8+106>: movl   $0x8048cfa,(%esp)
0x08048a94 <function8+113>: call   0x8048424 <puts@plt>
0x08048a99 <function8+118>: mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048a9c <function8+121>: leave  
0x08048a9d <function8+122>: ret
```

And so far I have managed to convert it to this in C:

```
    int function8(one, two){
        int a = 879130;
        int b = one;
        int c = two;
        int d = 0;

        d = (d / a * b * c);

        if(strcmp(b, (d + 4)) == 0){
            printf("You may enter using token %d", d);
        }
        else{
            puts("You may not enter.");
        }

        return d; 
    }

    int main(){
        int one, two = 0;
        function8(one, two); 
    }
```

I am know that

```
0x08048a59 <function8+54>:  mov    0x8049e50,%eax
```

and

```
0x08048a63 <function8+64>:  movl   $0x8048cd4,0x4(%esp)
```

are pointing to a particular address and value respectively (correct me if I'm wrong), but don't know if I have to call it or not. If so, how do I call that particular address?

Any help would be appreciated!

Just in case you guys need it, this is my current output when I create a binary using GCC and then run GDB to get the dump:

```
0x08048434 <function8+0>:   push   %ebp
0x08048435 <function8+1>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048437 <function8+3>:   sub    $0x28,%esp
0x0804843a <function8+6>:   movl   $0xd6a1a,-0x18(%ebp)
0x08048441 <function8+13>:  mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048444 <function8+16>:  mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
0x08048447 <function8+19>:  mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x0804844a <function8+22>:  mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
0x0804844d <function8+25>:  movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048454 <function8+32>:  mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048457 <function8+35>:  mov    %eax,%edx
0x08048459 <function8+37>:  sar    $0x1f,%edx
0x0804845c <function8+40>:  idivl  -0x18(%ebp)
0x0804845f <function8+43>:  imul   -0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x08048463 <function8+47>:  imul   -0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x08048467 <function8+51>:  mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x0804846a <function8+54>:  mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x0804846d <function8+57>:  add    $0x4,%eax
0x08048470 <function8+60>:  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x08048474 <function8+64>:  mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x08048477 <function8+67>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x0804847a <function8+70>:  call   0x8048364 <strcmp@plt>
0x0804847f <function8+75>:  test   %eax,%eax
0x08048481 <function8+77>:  jne    0x8048499 <function8+101>
0x08048483 <function8+79>:  mov    $0x80485a0,%eax
0x08048488 <function8+84>:  mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
0x0804848b <function8+87>:  mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
0x0804848f <function8+91>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048492 <function8+94>:  call   0x8048344 <printf@plt>
0x08048497 <function8+99>:  jmp    0x80484a5 <function8+113>
0x08048499 <function8+101>: movl   $0x80485bd,(%esp)
0x080484a0 <function8+108>: call   0x8048354 <puts@plt>
0x080484a5 <function8+113>: mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080484a8 <function8+116>: leave  
0x080484a9 <function8+117>: ret
```

Comment: Whose security is it that you're trying to crack?

Comment: It's a class project. Basically we have to change a jump equal to a jump not equal by changing the binary file and then create a C program out of it that will create the "same" binary.

Comment: Comment each line, and I'll comment on your question.

Comment: Compliments for your curiosity, but trying to understand the code was not part of the assignment. It's not hard to guess which instruction needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

strcmp compares two strings that are passed in as pointers. The code here :

```
0x08048a59 <function8+54>:  mov    0x8049e50,%eax
0x08048a5e <function8+59>:  add    $0x4,%eax
0x08048a61 <function8+62>:  mov    (%eax),%eax
0x08048a63 <function8+64>:  movl   $0x8048cd4,0x4(%esp)
0x08048a6b <function8+72>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048a6e <function8+75>:  call   0x8048434 <strcmp@plt>
```

is passing two pointers to strcmp, both of which are static/global data (not local, like you have in your C code). One is at 0x8048cd4 (that's the address of the string.. it's probably something in quotes : "example"). The other is a pointer load + 4 that's dereferenced. I'd recommend : (1) look at those addresses to see what's stored in them, and (2) if you're confused by the assembly pointer chasing, try writing simple C programs that call strcmp and seeing the resulting assembly.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is the part who is calling the strcmp as drivingon9 pointed.

```
0x08048a59 <function8+54>:  mov    0x8049e50,%eax
0x08048a5e <function8+59>:  add    $0x4,%eax
0x08048a61 <function8+62>:  mov    (%eax),%eax
0x08048a63 <function8+64>:  movl   $0x8048cd4,0x4(%esp)
0x08048a6b <function8+72>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048a6e <function8+75>:  call   0x8048434 <strcmp@plt>
```

The result value of the strcmp will be stored in the register EAX.
Thats why we have a test eax,eax in the code bellow:

```
0x0804847f <function8+75>:  test   %eax,%eax
0x08048481 <function8+77>:  jne    0x8048499 <function8+101>
0x08048483 <function8+79>:  mov    $0x80485a0,%eax
0x08048488 <function8+84>:  mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
```

The test eax, eax  tests if eax register is equal to 0.

i'm not sure what part of the code will let you do what you want, but you can try change the line

```
0x08048481 <function8+77>:  jne    0x8048499 <function8+101>
```

and change the instruction to a je(JUMP IF EQUAL) or a incondicional jump(JMP)